# how to call function OpenDlgFile(); ExeOutput for PHP

Tags: php, exe

I develop a standalone windows application in php using ExeOutput for PHP.in my application i using OpenDlgFile()(built in functions in ExeOutput for Php) how to call this function in my index.php page

http://www.exeoutput.com/help/choosingfilesupload

I referred this link but not working for me.please give me a example code use file upload control in ExeOutput for Php.

```
// UserMain
// This script contains special functions related to some of the events triggered by the application.
// You can then optionally add new commands.


function OnBeforeNavigate(NewURL, TargetFrame: String): Boolean;
begin
 // Before the application displays a page. Set Result to True to stop the operation.
 Result := False;
end;        

procedure OnPHPErrorMessage(ErrorMsg: String);
begin
 // When an error is returned by the PHP runtime.                                                                                       
end;

procedure OnNavigateComplete(URL: String);
begin
 // When a page has been displayed.
end;

function OnPubLoaded: Boolean;
begin          
 // When the application is starting.
 // Set Result to True if you want to exit immediately without any warning.
 Result := False;
end;

procedure OnPubBeingClosed;
begin
 // When the application is going to be closed.
end;               



procedure OnDisplayWindow(WindowName: String);
begin
 // When a window is going to be displayed (including main and secondary windows).
end;

procedure OnStartMainWindow;
begin
 // When the main window is going to be displayed (just before the homepage is shown).
end;       

function OpenDlgFile: String;
begin                                  
OpenFileDialog("Select a File", "*.*", "*.*", "All files (*.*)|*.*", "");
end;   

procedure OnCloseWindow(WindowName: String);
begin
 // When a window is closed by the user.
end;  



function OnTimer(TimerName: String): Boolean;
begin
 // Occurs when a specified amount of time, determined by StartTimer HEScript function, has passed.
 // Note: use StopTimer to disable the timer or set Result to True.
 Result := False;
end;

function OnInvalidPasswordAtStartup: Boolean;
begin
 // Occurs when an invalid global password is provided.
 // Note: set to True if you want the application NOT to display an error message and exit.
 Result := False;
end;

function OnExpiredPublication: Boolean;
begin                     
 // Occurs when the global expiration date is reached.
 // Note: set to True if you want the application NOT to display an error message and exit.
 Result := False;
end;

procedure OnTrayIconClick;
begin
 // The user clicks on the tray icon.
end;

procedure OnTrayIconDblClick;
begin
 // The user double-cclicks on the tray icon.
end;

procedure OnPrintPage;
begin
 // When a user wants to print the current page.
end;
```

And this is my Php code i am using

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="fname" />
<?php 
echo "Asking for filename...<br>"; 
// Executes HEScript to call the system dialog "Open"...
$filename = exo_return_hescriptcom("UserMain.OpenDlgFile", "Error"); 
// The $filename variable contains the full path to the file selected by the user. It can be passed to fopen for instance. 
if (empty($filename))
{
echo "You have not selected any file. Operation canceled<br>";
return;
} 
$pdf->load($filename); 
?>
```

it open file upload control while page loading..